# SQL: variable values inside of a where clause, or similar?

Tags: sql, date, where-clause, between

Situation:
Trying to get payrate of employee at 90 days after hire, and 1 year after hire.

I've been trying something like this:

```
SELECT payrate
FROM dbo.table
WHERE (table.checkdate BETWEEN table.startdate +90 AND table.startdate +97)
```

I know the above is far from valid, but it's just a quick example.

I think I need the +90 and +97, because the checks are done weekly, and might not fall on exactly the 90th day.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using SQL Server.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES payrate
FROM dbo.table t
WHERE t.checkdate >= dateadd(day, 90, t.startdate)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ? ORDER BY t.startdate);
```

The `?` for the for the column identifying each employee.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the other solution given gave me many duplicate rows. Your solution only gave me one row per employee which is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tagging on to the first answer.

```
SELECT t.employeeid, t.payrate
FROM dbo.table t
WHERE (
  --GET CHECKS BETWEEN THE 90 AND 97 DATE RANGE
  t.checkdate >= dateadd(day, 90, t.startdate) 
  AND
  t.checkdate <= dateadd(day, 97, t.startdate) 
)
```

For one year replace 90 and 97 with 365 and 372.

This is assuming that there is only one check/payrate per record within that 90 day date range.